# How do I use and view data from SQL Group By and SQL Aggregates with Dapper?

Tags: c#, dapper

If I have an SQL statement like,

```
SELECT Count(id) as TotalRows, transaction_date
FROM Accounts
Group By transaction_date
```

What do I use as a return type an display it in my View using Dapper Dot Net?  I tried using `ViewData["mydata"]` and I tried using `List<dynamic>`, but I could not iterate because the return type is `IActionResult` and as such does not have an Enumerator.  I can't cast it (I don't know how to) to a specific type with `IEnumerable` because there is not custom type like (Accounts, Person, etc.).  None of these have a property for enumerating.

I would like to not use Linq unless it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Create a POCO to represent your result set item

```
public class GroupedData
{
   public int TotalRows { set;get;}
   public DateTime TransactionDate { set;get;}
}
```

Using Dapper, execute the query and load result to a list of this class and pass that to your view

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   var groupedDataList = GetData();
   return View(groupedDataList);
}
private List<GroupedData> GetData()
{
   var q=@"SELECT Count(id) as TotalRows, 
               transaction_date as TransactionDate
          FROM Accounts
          Group By transaction_date";
   return yourSqlConnection.Query<GroupedData>(q).ToList();
}
```

Now make sure your view is strongly typed the same type you are passing from your action method (List of `GroupedData`). You can enumerate this list.

```
@model List<GroupedData>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <p>@item.TransactionDate</p>
  <p>@item.TotalRows</p>
}
```